# is this a setting failure? sql datatable changed but gridview not

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, dataset

my project has a gridview, which shows a sql datatable from sql database. after several days of work(and this is why i cannot show my whole code, because it´s a lot) I added 2 columns in the sql datatable. but when I run my program the old version of my datatable shows up. ?! I work with a dataset.  Anyone has idea?

Cheers b101

Edit: Naveen, I used the wizard to great a datasource. then I went in the form designer, clicked on the datasource, selected gridview and pulled it in the form. in the sql studio, I just created a table with one primary key. there are no other tables which are depend on it.

Comment: How you are connecting to DB ? Is it entity model? Give details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your updated question, you used wizard to create data-source.  In this case as per your selection the SQL Query would be generated. You need to update this query. There will be a `SqlDataSource` created  with a property `SelectCommand`. Check for it in the page and update the query to add new columns.

Example of datasource :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:database1ConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT column1 from yourtable"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

If you are working in Windows form, you will get the same wizard view on clicking of `ConfigureDataSource` of the control. You can update the query using that wizard.

Check this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171902%28VS.80%29.aspx) to know more about how to edit TableAdapters.

Comment: Well, if I open the dataset designer, i can see all all rows of my sql table including the missing two. in properties -> commandText the command also selects the 2 missing rows ?!

Comment: You were telling missing columns!!, I hope you are talking about columns, in that case, you might have to add column in the gridview. Update the gridview if you are adding columns manually.

Comment: sorry yes i talk about columns

Comment: Did you check your gridview? It has proper column design?

Comment: the datasource the  gridview has is the bindingsource. and the bindingsource, has as datasource the dataset. the dataset itsel has all columns... well

Comment: haha the gridview itself has the right table design  while not running the programm (F5)

Comment: I din't get you, can you explain more please

Comment: when I am in the designer form, there is a preview of my table in the gridview. when I make the gridview bigger, that I can see all columns the 2 missing tables are displayed. but when I run my program via F5 these 2 columns not apprear...

Comment: Nice, i deleted the gridview and the controll elements. and created it new and it works. -.- thx nevertheless naveen

Comment: Cool, but it would have better if you were able to solve the problem. Actually i got into confusion what you are using, finally i got it, you have to update your dataadapter since you are using dataset (.xsd). I have updated my answer with a link, may be it will help in future.